# When I do a GeoIP lookup, why does the nearby capital city come up instead?

Tags: ip-address, isp, ipv4, geoip

(I am starting this Q/A to help a mispost on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242826/why-is-an-ip-address-in-a-different-city)

I personally live in a smaller city outside of my State's capital city. Whenever I lookup my IP address then do a GeoIP lookup it responds with my State's capital city, not the city I live in. Why is this?

Comment: GeoIP is only as good as the database of IPs and locations behind it, and that is based on what ISPs and companies tell the database holders. It is not an accurate way of telling where anything on the internet actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 major reasons that result in less-accurate GeoIP mapping.

**1. GeoIP Database Maintenance**

IP Address blocks are basically purchased by an Internet Service Provider (ISP), who have a head office. The most basic conclusion would be that a customer on one of those IP addresses are in the same city as the head office. But in reality an ISP will be a nation-wide organisation.

**2. Your ISPs Routing**

An ISP could split up their IP-Address reservations into smaller blocks that are allocated to smaller cities and towns around the country. ISPs with ample IP Addresses might do this. But many more don't have spare IPv4 addresses - there are not enough.

**3. IP Address Exhaustion**

If a town with 100 people is allocated a block of 50 IP addresses, and only 1 is used; there might be another town with 50 people and allocated 20 IP addresses, but they need 40. The distribution of such a scarce resource is a waste of time. By having a single IP address pool for larger areas, that IP address pool will get better utilisation. But that isn't the worst part - many ISPs completely run out of IP addresses.

**4. NATing**

Mobile/Cell Phone Networks have to deal with a massive growth of internet-connected devices; most simply don't have enough to give every phone their own IPv4 Address. Network Address Translation (NAT) is a workaround that lets multiple devices share a single public IPv4 Address (or a pool of them). This means a single IP-Address could be used by any mobile device anywhere in the State/Country within the same hour. If a Single-IP address isn't strongly correlated to one device in one place, then it cannot be used for fine GeoIP resolution.

---

The future with IPv6

When your ISP lets you use IPv6, fewer of the reasons above will apply. There is a greater chance that you can have more accurate GeoIP for yourself (and others). But [2] will still be important - your ISP will need to break up their IPv6 allocation(s) and update the GeoIP database. It is possible that they can give customers static IP addresses, and specify an exact address, but you probably don't want them to do that.